# How to Access The form field values at the server side? Form passed through jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please anyone help me,

Here I am passing the form through the jquery ajax to the server side. I am not undestanding how to access this form field values at the server side.

```
function validateleavedays(form) {
    var TestVar = form.leavetype.value;
    var data = $('form').serialize();


            $.get("leaverequestvalidation.do?method=validateleavetypedays", data, function(responseJson) {
                return false;
            });
        }
```

Comment: can i know the server language: eg:- django,php,c#,nodejs, rubyonrails...etc

Comment: I am using java and j2ee.

Comment: aren't you mixing up java with javascript? the above code looks like jquery, and that's a javascript library...

Comment: ...and by the way, are you trying to do it all with javascript/jquery or are you using some server side script like php...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use request.getParameter("form input element name") to access the values on the server side. I suggest you should post the form rather than doing a get request.

Let me know if that works for you.

Incase you have checkboxes in the form, you would expect multiple values on the server side. You can retrieve the same using 
    String[] values = getParameterValues(“form checkbox name”);

Comment: How get the array of check box values.

Comment: This works fine but I have any array of checkboxs this check boxes are generated by ajax how to get thous values. those are there in the same form.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP, you can use the `$_GET` variable. It will have all your form elements stored in an array.

```php
$params = array();
parse_str($_GET, $params);
```